# Google Chrome https popup error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, asp-classic, https

I have a secure page.  In Chrome when I pop-up pages from that secure page, it displays an exclamation mark in both the parent and child address bars.

When viewed on it's own the child page shows as secure (no exclamation mark) according to Chrome.

How can I have popups from my secure page, and not induce these exclamation mark warnings?

Here's my popup code:

```
function popup(URL) {
        day = new Date();
        id = day.getTime();
        eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=800,height=550');");
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval` for *this*? I don't think it can be harmful this way, but it's at least not efficient. Moreover, you'll lose `id` when leaving that function, so `page#` is no longer accessible. BTW, do you have an example page, so we can test this issue? I can't reproduce this when testing this with Gmail (opening a new window from within the current one, both using `https`). You're sure that `URL` contains a URL with the `https` protocol?

Comment: "I can't reproduce this when testing this with Gmail (opening a new window from within the current one, both using https"...that's not a valid test.  Yes, my links are https.

Comment: Why isn't it a valid test? It uses the same methods. We can do further tests if you provide a link to an example page.

Comment: I won't provide a link b/c I do not wish to advertise a weakness on our secure page.

No, it's not a valid test, at all.  If you understood the problem, you would know that.

Comment: I'm getting a bit irritated here, because I think I fully understand your problem. Please try to explain *why* it's not a valid test, in your eyes. I'm opening a new window using the exact same method that you use, opening a URL with the same protocol (https) and domain and I do not get those exclamation marks. So, what's the *difference* between this test and yours?

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted.  I had 5 popups on my page.  Some of those popups had https links, but the content wasn't totally secure.  Once I secured all of the popups, the exclamation went away.